# dhcpcd --dumplease interface lists nothing on Android

Tags: android, client, dhcp

`dhcpcd --dumplease interface` lists nothing on Android even though my tablet just got an IP address. What should I write on the command-line to list the lease times received for the different IP addresses on Android?

Comment: Same here. That command blocks on my device or returns nothing is run from adb...

Comment: Do you know how to list the lease times then?

Comment: No, I'm having the same issue as you do: cannot list any interface. Seems to do nothing on Android...